# axios Promise.all never ends

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, async-await, axios

I am using  node.js with axios to get some url's, and I am iterating over an id using `promise.all()` but it never ends. Do I am missing something? `listCalls` is the array which has all the calls I want ( between 25-70 ) calls

```
const result = await Promise.all(listCalls.map(async (call) => await axios.get(call.url)));
console.log(result is, result);
```

But never arrives to display nothing.

Answer (score 1):

axios.get returns a promise. That's what you want to send to Promise.all:

```
const result = await Promise.all(listCalls.map(call => axios.get(call.url)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all returns an array with aggregated results. Example below should resolve with an array containing promise1, promise2, promise3 results or an error.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message)
});
```

Change your code to this and check results:

```
const result = await Promise.all(listCalls.map(async (call) => await axios.get(call.url))).then((values) => {
  console.log('result is', values);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error.message)
});
```